# Grails - not-null property references a null or transient value on lastUpdated Property

Tags: grails, grails-orm, quartz-scheduler

I have a Grails application that is running a periodic job that collects information from several domain objects and then updates records in a table for easy tracking and monitoring.

This project is using Grails 2.1.1

The job runs fine the first two or three times but then it begins failing.  The Error that is being thrown is

```
org.spingframework.dao.DataIntergrityViolationException:
not-null property references a null or transient vale:
Tracker.lastUpdated;
nested exception is org.hibernate.PropteryValueException:
not-null property references a null or tansient value: 
Tracker.lastUpdated
```

So, in my domain I have this:

```
package arena

import grails.plugin.multitenant.core.annotation.MultiTenant

@MultiTenant
class Tracker {
   static belongsTo = [ plan: Plan ]
   boolean active
   Integer produced
   Integer counted
   Integer failed
   Integer remaining
   Float percentDone
   Date lastUpdated

   static constraints = {
      plan(nullable:false)
      produced(nullable:true)
      failed(nullable:true)
      counted(nullable:true)
      remaining(nullable:true)
      percentDone(nullable:true)
   }
}
```

In the job I get each plan then update all of the properties except lastUpdated since that should be automagically updated at the time of the row update. It is causing my job to fail so not all of the plans trackers are getting updated accordingly.

Do I need to manually set the lastupdated?  I don't have to do that with any other domain objects.

The Job is executed every 2 hours. The gist of the process is that I collect all plans across all the tenant locations.  And for each plan I calculate values for each plan and update the tracker record.

```
def plans = Plan.createCriteria().list {
   projections {
      property("id")
   }
}

// update or create strawTracker objects
for (plan in plans) {
   def collection = Plan.get(plan)
   multiTenantService.doWithTenantId(collection.tenantId) {
      def tracker = Tracker.findByPlan(collection)
      if (!tracker) {
         tracker = new Tracker()
         tracker.merge(updateTracker(tracker, collection)).save(flush: true)
      } else {
         if (tracker.active && !collection.status.equals("done")) {
            // get info
            // println "Update tracker " + collection
            def tempTracker = new Tracker()
            tempTracker.merge(updateTracker(tracker, collection)).save(flush:true)
         }

def updateTracker(Tracker tracker, Plan plan) {
   def prodSum = 0
   def failSum = 0
   def countSum = 0

   plan?.Schedules?.each {
      // doing calculations here //
   }

   int tenant = plan.tenantId
   tracker.Plan = plan
   tracker.active = !plan.status.equals("done")
   tracker.produced = prodSum
   tracker.strawsFailed = failSum
   tracker.countedStraws = countSum
   tracker.remaining = plan.quantityOrdered == null? null : (plan.quantityOrdered - countSum)
   tracker.percentDone = plan.quantityOrdered == null? null : (countSum * 100 / plan.quantityOrdered)
   tracker.tenantId =  tenant
   return tracker
}
```

As stated before it runs successfully the first few times, then as users are updating plans and filling orders it begins failing and so some tracker information is updated correctly but some are not.

Comment: please post more about the job process.

Comment: i had the same error once. what i had to do was use `parent.addToChildren(new Child(...))` instead of `new Child(parent: parent)`. problem went away...